# Connect to Linux MongoDB server with Windows C# program

Tags: c#, linux, mongodb, ssh, centos7

To whom this may concern:

I am having difficulty (mainly due to my lack of knowledge in C# and IT) figuring out how to connect to a MongoDB server on Linux using a program designed in C#.

I am using CentOS7 with mongod running. I am able to connect MongoChef to the CentOS MongoDB server using SSH authentication. I am trying to create a SshStreamFactory class as follows using the IStreamFactory from MongoDB's API:

```
public class SshStreamFactory : IStreamFactory
{
    public Stream CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<Stream> CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am using SSH.NET by Renci to create a connection via SSH to my CentOS Server.

```
var sshClient = new SshClient("192.0.0.1", "user", "password");
sshClient.Connect();
```

I can't seem to figure out how to link the SshClient from SSH.NET to the SshStreamFactory from MongoDB, in order to have a persistent connection to my Linux MongoDB server.

Can anyone please advise?

If you have any alternative means of connecting to a Linux MongoDB server that I can use in .NET, I would appreciate if you would share.

Thanks kindly!

Comment: with MongoDB C# driver, you can connect directly to MongoDB without any SSH. Why do you want to use SSH ?

Comment: x -- it seems the only way i can connect from a windows computer to a linux server with MongoDB is with SSH. I can't seem to use a direct connection via the server's IP address and MongoDB port, unless I'm missing something. I've tried setting SELinux to permissive and disabling the firewall to no avail.

Comment: You can use the connection string : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/

Comment: Bind to LAN IP : https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

Comment: Yep, that third link did the trick. Thanks!!